# Highest number of threads: Jmeter vs. WCat 6.3

Tags: jmeter, load-testing, wcat

I want to use the highest possible number of threads on single computer.
I tried JMeter and for me it's not enough. I have only few computers to use.
Is WCat generating higher number of threads which I can reasonable simultaneously run than JMeter?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

As mentioned above, you have at least a set of another options for your case, instead of wcat usage:

- using Jmeter:

  - try to apply resource reductions you can find at least in jmeter's [wiki](http://wiki.apache.org/jmeter/) and [best practices](http://jmeter.apache.org/usermanual/best-practices.html#lean_mean);
  - try [Distributed Testing](http://jmeter.apache.org/usermanual/jmeter_distributed_testing_step_by_step.pdf) scenarios;
- [Gatling](http://gatling-tool.org/)
- [Tsung](http://tsung.erlang-projects.org/)

Answer (score 1):

If by "threads" you actually mean concurrent users, [Gatling](http://gatling-tool.org) could be a good choice. For example, I ran yesterday a test with 10,000 concurrent users and 1000 hits/sec (the application under test couldn't go higher).

Then, be aware that the load you'll be able to generate from a single server will depend on your use case. At some point, you might hit the NIC limit and then you'll have to scale out.

Answer (score 0):

Are you sure the 2 tools can be compared :
- can you do complex scripting with wcat ?
- variabilize data ?

If you aim at simple hit/s then wcat or apache bench may be enough.
If you are trying more complex scenarios then JMeter can run high number of threads provided you follow best practices.